# SpringXD's field-value-counter doesn't work after splitting Json Object Array into individual Object

Tags: arrays, json, spring-xd

Let's say my SpringXD source data contains an array of json objects (dogs) and I want to count a field value (dogType) that each array element (dog) has.

To do so, first I define the input stream and use splitter to decompose the array.

1. Define Splitter

   xd:>stream create dogstream --definition "http | splitter --expression=#jsonPath(payload,'$.[*]') | log" --deploy

   xd:>http post --data "[{\"dog\": \"poodle\"}, {\"dog\": \"chihuahua\"}, {\"dog\":\"poodle\"}]"

2015-10-21T10:52:31-0700 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO sink.dogstream- {dog=poodle}

2015-10-21T10:52:31-0700 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO sink.dogstream- {dog=chihuahua}

2015-10-21T10:52:31-0700 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO sink.dogstream- {dog=poodle}

So splitter works.

2. Next, add a field-value-counter to above stream

   stream create --name dogCounter --definition "tap:stream:dogstream > field-value-counter --fieldName=dog" --deploy

**Now, here's the QUESTION**
If I post more data (dogs), SpringXD should create the field-value-counter (lazy creation, I guess) and increment the dog counter for each dog type but I don't see anything happening.
The rest endpoint (http://localhost:9393/metrics/field-value-counters/)  doesn't show the counter that I created.

Can anybody think about the reason?  Does SpringXD support this?  I think this is a legitimate use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

**1. Wrong Type**

Per the documententation, the field value counter only supports `POJO`, `Tuple` or `JSON String`.
`jsonPath` emits a `LinkedHashMap`; so we need to convert it back to JSON...

```
xd:>stream create dogstream --definition "http | splitter --expression=#jsonPath(payload,'$.[*]') --outputType=application/json | log" --deploy
```

Here, I used the `outputType` property for that.

**2. Wrong Tap Point**

You are tapping the wrong part of the stream; by default, taps are applied to the first `|`; you need to tap after the splitter...

```
xd:>stream create --name dogCounter --definition "tap:stream:dogstream.splitter > field-value-counter --fieldName=dog" --deploy
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks @GaryRussell.  I learned two new features.  I see now 2 poodles and 1 chihuahua!    {"name":"dogCounter","links":[{"rel":"self","href":"http://localhost:9393/metrics/field-value-counters/dogCounter"}],"counts":{"chihuahua":1.0,"poodle":2.0}}

Comment: It is customary here to mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem (click the tick/check mark); it will help others.